# Multisite not using subdomains as hostname in from address when sending emails

Tags: multisite, email, subdomains, wp-mail

I have a Multisite installation where I'm facing somekind of bug relating the hostname used when WordPress sends emails (I've test it with WordPress admin emails and Contact Form 7).

For example, if I try to send an email from `wordpress@site.example.com` the email gets sent but the from address is somehow changed to `wordpress@example-cname-id.elb.amazonaws.com`. Where `example-cname-id.elb.amazonaws.com` is the alias I have in my DNS for the domain `site.example.com`, which is one of the sites in the Multisite . Weirdly enough, if I instead try to send the email from `wordpress@example.com` the From Address doesn't change. The latter wouldn't be a workaround since I really need to send the emails from a subdomain hostname, which in this example would be `wordpress@site.example.com`

Some extra details:

- If I delete the CNAME record and replace it for an A record the
  From Address is not changed. Yet, this option would not work as a
  solution since it would require to change all the DNS and servers setup.
- I don't face this bug in single-site installations with a similar DNS set up (also using subdomains aswell).
- I'm using WordPress 4.9.8.
- The Multisite is on Subdomain mode.

has anyone ever faced a similar issue?